# Kill the process from the kernel

Tags: linux

I am trying to use `kill` but inside the Linux kernel so I used `sys_kill` but this one does not work for me
it is giving me an error
so anyone knows what I have to use to kill the process inside the kernel not in the user command

### so my question in different from how could I use the system call from the kernel

to the one who already asked me to make it clear .. yes I am trying to kill one process when the Linux got a packet from the network
so after 1000 packets Linux has to kill process number 17722
I used kill, kill_sys but it does not work because I am in the kernel level not the user level

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you are trying to do. Are you writing a program? What exactly do you want to kill? What do you mean by "inside the kernel"?

Comment: I've got some spare puncuation over here if you want some. Particularly some full stops `...` and commas `,,,`. Please [edit] your question to make it easier to understand (and read).

Answer (score 5):

`sys_kill` is a system call.  System calls are for *userspace* apps to call into the kernel.

If you want to `kill` a process from within the kernel, take a look at `kill_proc_info`.

Comment: kill_proc_info() does the job for me (I'm not a very experienced kernel hacker so I cannot comment whether it's the right function use). However, beware of the following pitfall: It takes a virtual pid, not a global pid. You won't find that bug before you use your first pid namespace (container).

Answer (score 0):

it is not uncommon (or at least, not unknown) for the kernel to make system calls ... but you first have to do a bit of hackery so that you can pass kernel virtual addresses as arguments (at a minimum - there are other hurdles and traps, all of which make it something that you should avoid doing if you can ... e.g. not a good idea to do this from an interrupt handler). [this blog article](http://pointer-overloading.blogspot.com.au/2013/09/linux-doing-system-call-from-kernel.html) does a reasonable job of explaining it.

Comment: Article is now out of date. https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20180325162527.GA17492@light.dominikbrodowski.net/T/#u / https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/Documentation/process/adding-syscalls.rst#do-not-call-system-calls-in-the-kernel